# Does "shouldn't" always take "should" as a question tag?

Tags: question-tags

Which usage is correct?

> - You shouldn't take sugar, should you?
> - You shouldn't take sugar, will you?

Comment: I detect a difference of emhasize and,  as I have to say over and over again, it all depends on context, on the effect the speaker is trying to achieve!

Comment: The second one is incorrect, with the comma.  Notice how in Andrew Leach's excellent answer, he subtly replaced the offending comma with a semicolon.

Answer (score 9):

In simple usage, the question tag always mirrors the clause which makes the statement:

> You shouldn't take sugar, should you?
>   You won't take sugar, will you?

Changing the question tag makes it into a statement and a supplementary question. Note the change in written punctuation, which may not be so obvious in speech.

> You shouldn't take sugar; will you? (That is, *will you do that anyway?*)
>   You won't take sugar; should you? (That is, *should you do that even if you have decided not to?*)

The first, normal, usage is a simple question tag to confirm the assumption implied in the statement. The second usage is actually **inviting a contradiction** of the assumption.

Comment: So I'm correct in saying "it all depends on context, on the effect the speaker is trying to achieve"!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández Sometimes the difference is easy to demonstrate and explain; sometimes it's actually necessary to ask for context.

Comment: Changing the question tag sounds terribly wrong. It feels like a cracked mirror. In some logical sense, it is probably grammatical, but I can't imagine someone meaning to use it coherently. It might be said "You won't take sugar. (pause) Should you?", but that's a very different thing, it's not a question tag.