# Usage of “isn’t it” in the sentence

Tags: word-usage, question-tags

Being a non-native speaker of English, I am less aware about the distinction between Asian and standard English. While conversing with my client, I came to realize that *isn't it* is used wrong in this sentence:

> You didn’t wait for us before you went to meet him **isn’t it**?

According to him, that *isn’t it* should be replaced with *didn’t you*.  Could anyone explain why it must be *didn’t you* instead of *isn’t it* there?

Comment: Using *isn't it?* as a general-purpose tag question seems quite common in Asian/Indian English. Standard English makes the verb in the tag match the main verb: "You didn't wait, did you?" There are quite a number of questions in ELU about this sort of tag.

Comment: It’s the question-tag rule.  I posted this a few days ago.  Just a minute.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/qu_tags.htm) for some rules for how to construct traditional question tags in English, including accounting for negatives and auxiliaries. Note that some speakers also use simpler tags like “eh?” or “right?”, or even just “ok?” at the ends of their statements; “you know?” can be an all-purpose question tag in some speakers.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95846 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95121 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64646 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/78344 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2367 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5135 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/62157 and doubtless many more.

Comment: I think many crore of people are confused about this, isn't it?

Comment: @JohnLawler The  Himālayas do be shadowing their understands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subject and verb must agree, and a second reference must use the same subject.  So it's "You didn’t wait, did you?" "It's a lovely day, isn't it?"  "I dropped the ball, didn't I?"